# Ocasionally my application would crash, why?

Tags: android

Like the title says ocasionally my application crashes and I am not sure why it does it.

Here is the code:

This is the where I get the input: 
           public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                // Perform action on key press
                String query = edittext.getText().toString();
                // gets the text and makes sure its a string
                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,
                        DissertationActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("query1", query);
                startActivity(intent);

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String query = edittext.getText().toString();
            // gets the text and makes sure its a string

            Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,
                    DissertationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("query1", query);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
 }
```

// Second activity that does the retrieving of the results

```
         public class DissertationActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public ArrayList<String> book_Array = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

String href = "";
String href1 = "";
String search_Word = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    search_Word = extras.getString("query1");

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_1,
            book_Array);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    new LoadingProgressBar().execute();

}

class LoadingProgressBar extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DissertationActivity.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.pDialog.setMessage("Loading");
        this.pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        try {
            Document doc = null;
            Document guestLink = null;

            guestLink = Jsoup.connect("https://aulib.abdn.ac.uk:443/F")
                    .get();
            Element link = guestLink.select("p > a").first();
            href1 = link.attr("href");
            href = href1.substring(0, href1.length() - 2); // removes -0
                                                            // from
                                                            // the

            // href_Array.add(href); //adds href to the array because string
            // wont add to the public var.
            doc = Jsoup.connect(
                    href + "&request=" + search_Word
                            + "&find_code=WRD&adjacent=N&x=0&y=0").get();
            // System.out.println(doc);
            Elements headings = doc.select("td:eq(3)");
            // System.out.println(headings);
            for (Element heading : headings) {
                // System.out.println(heading.text());
                String j = heading.text();

                book_Array.add(j);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        book_Array.remove(0);
        book_Array.remove(1);
        book_Array.remove(2);
        book_Array.remove("Search");
        book_Array.remove(" | ");
        book_Array.remove(0);

        pDialog.dismiss();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                    long id) {

                int query = position;

                Intent intent = new Intent(DissertationActivity.this,
                        FullDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("href", href);
                intent.putExtra("query1", (int) query);
                intent.putExtra("search_Word", search_Word);

                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });
        return null;
    }

}
```

}

Here is the stack trace (sorry I don't know how to format this):

```
04-26 17:17:20.722: E/WindowManager(8576):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:406)
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at com.library_app.DissertationActivity$LoadingProgressBar.doInBackground(DissertationActivity.java:102)
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at com.library_app.DissertationActivity$LoadingProgressBar.doInBackground(DissertationActivity.java:1)
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
04-26 17:19:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     ... 4 more
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608): Activity com.library_app.DissertationActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@407aadc8 that was originally added here
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.library_app.DissertationActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@407aadc8 that was originally added here
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:259)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:465)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at com.library_app.DissertationActivity$LoadingProgressBar.onPreExecute(DissertationActivity.java:59)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at com.library_app.DissertationActivity.onCreate(DissertationActivity.java:49)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2953)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
04-26 17:19:41.879: E/WindowManager(8608):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It will only crash sometimes. It is always after I search for something. I have also noticed that if I go back using the button on the phone and try to search for something again it crashes, not all times but only some times.

What would be causing the crash? How would I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: @Kolink maybe it doesn't like you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0"
```

shows you that you are trying to access an array that has a size of 0 (empty)

```
"at java.util.ArrayList.remove"
```

tells me that its being caused by you trying to remove items from your array.

Likely, one of these lines:

```
book_Array.remove(0);
book_Array.remove(1);
book_Array.remove(2);
book_Array.remove("Search");
book_Array.remove(" | ");
book_Array.remove(0);
```

is causing it since you aren't checking anywhere to make sure your book_array actually has those values.

```
at com.library_app.DissertationActivity$LoadingProgressBar.doInBackground(DissertationActivity.java:102)
```

gives you the exact line that is causing your exception so you can check that line and make sure you validate your values prior to executing it. (Double click that line in logcat and it will take you to that line of code if you're using Eclipse)

Comment: Thanks! that seemed to have fixed it!